# LOG Database query

Tags: php, logging, pdo

I need to record a log of each transaction in the database, but I noticed a different behavior using COMMIT and not using.
When I use commit, each turn in the loop is practically nil, and when I do not use commit time is larger.
I wonder if this behavior is normal and would have some way to manage time accurately.
thank you

```
$microtimeA = microtime( true );
$pdo->beginTransaction();

$i=1;
while($i<=5)
{
    $microtimeB = microtime( true );
    $stmt = $pdo-> prepare( "INSERT INTO BLOG ( TITLE ) VALUES ( $i ) ");
    $stmt-> execute();
    $i++;
    echo "<p>" , number_format( microtime( true ) - $microtimeB , 4 ) , "</p>";
}
$pdo-> commit();

echo "<p>[" , number_format( microtime( true ) - $microtimeA , 4 ) , "]</p>";
```

Commit:
1: 0.0003
2: 0.0002
3: 0.0002
4: 0.0002
5: 0.0002
[0.0228]

no Commit:
1: 0.0149
2: 0.0197
3: 0.0416
4: 0.0135
5: 0.0332
[0.1229]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database is flushing data to disk when transactions are committed.  This is generally a slow operation, as it requires waiting at least one revolution of a spinning hard disk.

In your "no commit" case, your database will be auto-committing every transaction.  Hence you have 5 separate disk flushes.

In your "commit" case, you only flush to disk once.

The numbers back this up: 0.1229 is very nearly five times 0.0228